# Get the difference from data in Swift and data in database

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite, dictionary

A table in database have two column: ID and Value

In my project there are another data in a dictionary that key is ID and value is Value.

I want to get difference: Data that are in the dictionary and are not in the database. If these both data were in database, I could use SQL commands "Except" or "Not Exist" to get the difference like below image.
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

I use [SQLiteDB](https://github.com/FahimF/SQLiteDB) that the result of query is a dictionary like this:

`[["ID":"id1", "Value": "val1"], ["ID":"id2", "Value": "val2"],...]`

Also notice that both columns should be considered while compare these two data (dictionary and data in db).

Answer (score 0):

```
// here we get intersection of new data and data we have
let intersection = dataSet1.filtered { data in dataSet2.contains(where: { $0.id == data.id })}
// delete elements from dataSet1 which belongs to intersection
let dataSet1MinusDataSet2 = dataSet1.filter { data in intersection.contains(where: { data.id == $0.id })}
```

I've written code here without any Xcode so errors in syntax is possible but I think you will get the idea